# Update fails without error

Tags: class, dml, method

I have below class where update on mycallsInc not happening. Can someone please help me?

```
public void Publish() {
    List<Incident_abv__c> selIncs = (List<Incident_abv__c>)contr.getSelected();
    for(Incident_abv__c inc:selIncs) {
        inc.status_abv__c = 'Open';
        inc.Report_Publish_Date_abv__c = Date.today();
        if(inc.Rep_abv__c !=null)
            inc.OwnerId = inc.Rep_abv__c;
    }        
    update selIncs;

    List<SObject> myCalls = [SELECT Call_abv__c FROM Incident_Transaction_abv__c];
    //Set<Id> resultIds = (new Map<Id,SObject>(myCalls)).keySet();
    List <Call2_vod__c> myCallsInc = (List <Call2_vod__c>) myCalls;
    //List<Call2_vod__c> Call= new List<Call2_vod__c>();
    for(Call2_vod__c ita : myCallsInc )  {   
        attribute = [SELECT count() FROM Incident_Transaction_Line_Item_abv__c WHERE (Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__c=:ita.id
             or Call_Sample_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Parent_Call_vod__c=:ita.id) or (Call_detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__c=:ita.id
             or Call_detail_abv__r.Call2_vod__r.Parent_Call_vod__c=:ita.id)
             ];
        if(ita.Incidents_Count__c!=attribute)
            ita.Incidents_Count__c=attribute; 
        System.debug('Saikat_N@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
    }
    System.debug('D_N@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@');
    update myCallsInc ;

    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO, 'Successfully Published'));
}
```

Comment: Does this code compile correctly? I have tabbed out your code so that it is more readable.

Comment: Yes Barcotter. It compiles but updates are not happening

Comment: Try add some debugging to see what `Id` is being returned by `ita.id`.

Comment: @SFDC_GEEK - please post an answer to this so we can clear it from the open question list

Comment: I don't understand how this code can compile. It should throw an exception like System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type List<Incident_Transaction_abv__c> to List<Call2_vod__c>